# doctype is changing how my page appears

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-9, doctype

There is this strange behavior where my page was alright when it had no `doctype` (yes, the document mode was Quirks without doctype). Then I had to fix few things on it and adding a `doctype` (i.e changed document mode to standards) solved the issue but that introduced newer problems :(

This problem is particular to IE9 and its a GWT application.

The doctype added is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`
Earlier the login screen was looking right in the middle of the screen and style applied to it was

```
#login_form {
left: 40%;
top: 80px;
```

}

But now after adding the doctype and `without changing my html or css`, the login form appears to the right most of the screen. I dont understand how doctype can change this behavior

Comment: as you kind of answered it yourself. without doctype its in quirks mode and they will look different. try the new html5 type.

Comment: did that too...same results as said :)

Comment: try absolute positioning. and `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: it needs to have a width too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first check go through **GWT IE9 Tips** [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9) and ensure that IE9 is not loading in IE8 or lesser compatibility mode. You can use IE9 Dev Tools ( use F12 to launch it )

Also make sure you do not forget to add GWT's ie9 permutation to your module.gwt.xml .

Answer (score 0):

A Transitional DOCTYPE may be used when you have a lot of legacy markup that cannot easily be converted to comply with a `Strict DOCTYPE`. But Strict is what you should be aiming for.

When you add the DOC-TYPE to `Strict` ,Then You have to make sure that your HTML(XML) should be very well formatted (ex" forgetting end tag, writing `/>` instead of `</xxx>`). And some of the elements and attributes also not supported by the Strict DTD.

Coming to your problem the generated html content may(?) have some deprecated content which causing the problem,its somewhat pain to dig into the html and finding the deprecated elements,So iwould like to suggest [XHTML DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp) (which allows you to add modules) or  [Transactional DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp).

[Check the unsupported elements and Attributes here by Strict DTD](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup/)